# Javascript on change update input values in foreach

Tags: javascript

So I have to update values in each form from one drop down elemnt

Here is code from my group select box

```
              echo $this->Form->input('groups', ['options' => $groups, 'id' => 'groups', 'class' => 'selectpicker', 'label' => false, "onchange"=>"updateGroupId(this.value)"]);
```

Here is code where I generate forms

```
<table class="table table-striped">
       <tbody>
       <?php foreach($allProducts as $product): ?>
         <tr>
             <td>
                <form class="form-inline" name="uploadform-<?= $product->id ?>" id="uploadform-<?= $product->id ?>" onsubmit="return checkInput<?= $product->id ?>()" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/<?= $product->id ?>" method="post">
                  <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                    <span><i class="zmdi zmdi-upload zmdi-hc-fw"></i><?= __('Upload CSV') ?></span>
                    <input id="browsefiles-<?= $product->id ?>" name="uploadcsv" type="file" required="required" />
                    <span id="errornotification-<?= $product->id ?>" class="hidden"><?= __('Select CSV File') ?></span>
                  </span>
                  <input type="text" name="group_id-<?= $product->id ?>" id="group_id-<?= $product->id ?>" value="<?= key($groups) ?>" />
                </form>
             </td>
         </tr>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
       </tbody>
     </table>
```

And here is my javascript code

```
<?php
$i=0;
foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
?>
  function updateGroupId(ish){
    document.forms["uploadform-<?= $product->id ?>"]["group_id-<?= $product->id ?>"].value = ish;
  } } ?>
```

With this code I can update values on change only for last input, but I need for all inputs (groups_id).

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out an answer, so if somebody need solution here it is!

So, this is how to change values on all inputs with **same** **name** using select box (on.change function)

*Select box*
select input need ->

```
"onchange"=>"updateGroupId(this.value)"
```

input for change

```
<input type="hidden" name="group_id" value="<?= key($groups) ?>" />
```

And JS code

```
function updateGroupId(ish){
      var group_ids = document.getElementsByName('group_id');
      for (var i=0;i<group_ids.length;i++) {
        group_ids[i].value = ish;
      }
    }
```